# nodejs pool.query and functions

Tags: node.js

I am atm coding a vgo gambling site. And i have run into a problem. I cant get this to work, and i cant figure out why. Does anyone know what the problem is?

```
         if(msg.startsWith('/cancelflip') && ( user.rank == 100)) {
         if(args = /^\/cancelflip ([0-9]*)/.exec(msg)) {
                pool.query('SELECT citemss FROM cfs WHERE id = ?', [args[1]], function(e,r) {
                    if(e) throw e;
                pool.query('SELECT cuser FROM cfs WHERE id = ?', [args[1]], function(er, ro) {
                    if(er) throw er;
                pool.query('SELECT tradelink FROM users WHERE uid = ?', ro[0].cuser, function(err, ror) {
                    if(err) throw err;

                var items_p1 = r[0].citemss.split(',');

                ET.ITrade.SendOffer({trade_url: ror[0].tradelink, items_to_send: items_p1.join(','), expiration_time: 86400, message: 'VGODiamond.net - Cancelled Coinflip'}, (err, res) => {
                    if(err) throw err;

            if(!res.hasOwnProperty('response')) return socket.emit('msg', res.message, "error");

            if(res.response.offer.state == 2) {
                Offers[res.response.offer.id] = {
                    user: user.uid,
                };
            }

                socket.emit('user trade', res.response.offer.id);
                });

        });
    });
});
                pool.query('DELETE FROM cfs WHERE id = ?', [args[1]], setTimeout(function(errr, rorr) {
                    delete CFs[args[1]];

                    io.sockets.emit('coinflip', 'remove', [args[1]]);

                    sendCFStatistics();
                }, 3000));
    }
}
```

Comment: kindly add error messages, error stack, line you are facing issue.

Comment: There isnt any error messages, and i do not know what line i am facing issues with. The thing is just that the function ET.ITrade.SendOffer doesnt work. And i dont know if its the inputs i have made, or the function itself :)

Comment: try to debug the code & check whether you got the expected values in the variables.

Comment: I dont get any variables when debugging the code. There is no output what so ever. What can the problem be? :/

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by giving a timer on the deleting row query.